# Selecting rows in a dataframe where columns match and taking max

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So this is a simplified version of my full problem, but will hopefully help more people if it's more generic.

So I'm using a Pandas DataFrame that's arbitrarily big (large enough to not write a bunch of simple conditionals). Say it looks something like this:

```
member    group    score
1         1        56
1         1        432
1         1        43 
2         1        44
2         1        555
2         2        90
2         2        101
```

And say this list goes on for quite a while. My goal is to compare only the score of rows where they have both the same member and group as another row, and take not only the max of those rows but also how much of a max it is and store it in a new data frame. For example, the finished data frame would look like:

```
member    group    max    max by
1         1        432    376
2         1        555    511
2         2        101    11
```

I have no idea and I have not found any hint as to how to compare rows like that without saying `df['member'==1]`, but there are too many different values for member and group for me to do this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "how much of a max it is"?

Comment: Could you explain why it is 376 not 389

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you want to know the max in each group and by how much the max is greater than the score in the first row of the group:

```
df1 = df.groupby(["group", "member"]).agg(["first", "max"]).reset_index()
df1.columns = "member", "group", "first", "max"
df1["max by"] = df1["max"] - df1["first"]
#   member  group  first  max  max by
#0       1      1     56  432     376
#1       1      2     44  555     511
#2       2      2     90  101      11
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `np.ptp`
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

```
df.groupby(['member','group'])['score'].agg({'max':'max','max by':np.ptp}).reset_index()
Out[8]: 
   member  group  max  max by
0       1      1  432     389
1       2      1  555     511
2       2      2  101      11
```

---

EDIT : I will keep the "worng" one here :) cause I like this `np.ptp`

Here you go :~)

```
df.groupby(['member','group'])['score'].agg({'max':'max','max by':lambda g: g.max() - g.iloc[0]}).reset_index()
Out[17]: 
   member  group  max  max by
0       1      1  432     376
1       2      1  555     511
2       2      2  101      11
```

Comment: I think there is a mistake in the fist row.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ is that ok now ?~ :)

Comment: No, it needs to be 376, not 389.. I think

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ This question confused me ... ok, let me fix it

Comment: fix it , LOL :)

Comment: @Wen - I think your last solution is very nice, but unfortunately `FutureWarning: using a dict on a Series for aggregation
is deprecated and will be removed in a future version` :(

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [DYZ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46208902/4909087), a little cleaner.

```
df.groupby(['member', 'group']).score.agg(['max', 'first'])
df = df.assign(max_by=df.diff(-1, axis=1)['max'])\
                         .drop('first', 1).reset_index()
df

   member  group  max  max_by
0       1      1  432   376.0
1       2      1  555   511.0
2       2      2  101    11.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think delete column `first` is not necessary, cleaner is rename it after [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) subtracted columns:

```
df = (df.groupby(['member', 'group'])['score']
       .agg(['max', 'first'])
       .assign(first = lambda x: x['max'] - x['first'])
       .rename(columns={'first':'max by'})
       .reset_index())
print (df)
   member  group  max  max by
0       1      1  432     376
1       2      1  555     511
2       2      2  101      11
```